# CommonsMultipartFile size is 0

Tags: java, multipart

I trying this code and the image exists but when I try to create a CommonsMultipartFile the size is zero.

```
File file = new File("[image]");
DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "image/png", false, file.getName(), (int) file.length() , file.getParentFile());
fileItem.getOutputStream();
MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with this

```
DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "image/png", true, file.getName(), (int)file.length() , file.getParentFile());
InputStream input =  new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream os = fileItem.getOutputStream();
int ret = input.read();
while ( ret != -1 )
{
    os.write(ret);
    ret = input.read();
}
os.flush();
MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
Assert.assertTrue(multipartFile.getSize() > 0);
```

Comment: I can't use MockMultipartFile. I tried it but when I call a external service to upload the image, it gives me an error because it needs a FileItem.

Comment: @ClaraMG check the new response i changed to do not use MockMultipartFile

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked! although now I have another problem with parsing...
` org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer`

Comment: @ClaraMG cool, could you validate the answer as valid? so other people could use it? And for the parsing if you want to create a different question go ahead so people can help with it

Comment: Done it! I find out a little more by my side! But thanks!